# texture access in vertex shaders in stage3d?

Tags: flash, shader, gpu, stage3d

is it possible to perform texture access in vertex shaders in stage3d and flash 11.4/air 3.4?

if it is not possible, is there another way to implement efficient "stateful memory" from frame to frame while remaining 100% on the GPU on stage3d?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, but it is not possible. And I am afraid there is no any way to save data and use it another frame.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I don't know anything about stage3d, but I'm guessing that it's using OpenGL or DirectX under-the-hood. It will need to use Vertex Texture Fetch (VTF) for OpenGL (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Texture_Fetch) or Vertex Texture Samplers for DirectX (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206339(v=vs.85).aspx). Both are niche features. Hope that helps.